# Yii Framework and HAS_ONE relation with millions of rows

Tags: mysql, yii, rows, relation

Good afternoon.

I have a model called 'Cliente' and another called 'Acct'. The ratio is 1 'Cliente' for many 'Acct'. When I use a has_one relationship, it fetches all the millions of 'Acct' to pick only one of these results.

Statement of the model in relation 'Cliente':

```
'accts' => [
            self::HAS_MANY,
            'Acct',
            'cliente_id',
],

'lastAcct' => [
            self::HAS_ONE,
            'Acct',
            'cliente_id',
            'order' => 'acct.id DESC',
],
```

Answer (score 2):

In Yii (Yii1 as well as Yii2), creating a "Has One" relationship does **not** automatically apply a `LIMIT 1` to the query. You can read more about the reasoning behind it here: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/pull/2113

You should manually add the limit clause, like so:

```
'lastAcct' => [
            self::HAS_ONE,
            'Acct',
            'cliente_id',
            'order' => 'acct.id DESC',
            'limit' => '1'
],
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer, sir.

This 'limit' to enter the main query and not only in relation, for example, if you search thousands of 'clients' with the last 'acct' in each will not work, will get only one 'cliente'.

Complementing ...

To solve this I use a subquery, for example:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN `radacct` `acct` ON ((acct.username = t.login) AND (acct.radacctid = (SELECT radacctid FROM `radacct` `acct_subquery` WHERE acct_subquery.username = t.login GROUP BY acct_subquery.username ORDER BY acct_subquery.radacctid DESC LIMIT 1)))
```

But what worries me is that after this subquery be too cool with millions of results, it is a must do and ERP reports, weekly, monthly, yearly and since he started the company.